# testing php function with poster extention

Tags: php, json, testing, encoding, poster

I made a simple API to get the data from the database to be viewd at android app

I have a Problem testing my php functions

example of the  functions:-

```
<?php
include 'json_config.php';
function get_city(){
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");
$return=array();
//$country_name=$_POST['country_name'];

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM city") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["city"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        // Full texts   id  dead_name   masged_name     gender  salah       notes   date    city_name   hour    min 
        $region_subscribt = array();
        $region_subscribt["id"] = $row["id"];
        $region_subscribt["city_name"] = $row["city_name"];
        $region_subscribt["region_name"] = $row["notes"];
        $region_subscribt["notes"] = $row["country_name"];
    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["city"], $region_subscribt);
}


// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
} else {
// no products found
$response["fail"] = 0;


// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
}//end of the function

// get_city();
?>
```

when I using poster extention with firefox and put at the content , I got no data 
when I put at the content

```
 getcity();
```

but when I call the function inside the php file  I got the data correctly !

How to pass the values at the httprequest to use the returned  json at another app !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the method name as a parameter not as a content and then check the method name and call the code you need.

see this snapshot

```
if(isset($_GET['method_name']) && $_GET['method_name']) == 'get_city') {
     get_city();
}
```

you also need to set the content type as following

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

your final code will be something like this

```
<?php
include 'json_config.php';
function get_city(){
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");
$return=array();
//$country_name=$_POST['country_name'];

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM city") or die(mysql_error());

header('Content-type: application/json');

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["city"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        // Full texts   id  dead_name   masged_name     gender  salah       notes   date    city_name   hour    min 
        $region_subscribt = array();
        $region_subscribt["id"] = $row["id"];
        $region_subscribt["city_name"] = $row["city_name"];
        $region_subscribt["region_name"] = $row["notes"];
        $region_subscribt["notes"] = $row["country_name"];
    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["city"], $region_subscribt);
}


// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
} else {
// no products found
$response["fail"] = 0;


// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
}//end of the function
if(isset($_GET['method_name']) && $_GET['method_name']) == 'get_city') {
 get_city(); }
?>
```

and here is some very good and pretty easy tutorial summarize the whole precess
[Create a Basic Web Service Using PHP, MySQL, XML, and JSON](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)

Comment: Thanks alot Dear Islam , it was really very helpful , you reserve more than 2h from searching , thanks a million , it works now